# Azure API Management - Regression testing and Performance testing of APIs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-api-management

Are there any built-in options to perform Regression testing and Performance testing of APIs in Azure API Management? If not, are there any options to do that within the Azure ecosystem (like VSTS Performance tests tool etc.)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are no built-in options to perform `Regression testing` that available in Azure. But for performance testing, there are some.

### Regression Testing

For regression.I'd recommend going with manual testing like creating `Test Plan`, `Test Cases` execute/test them manually using VSTS

1. [Creating a Test Plan in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/create-a-test-plan?view=vsts)
2. [Creating a Test Case in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/create-test-cases?view=vsts)
3. [Run Manual Test in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/run-manual-tests?view=vsts)

### Load/Performance Testing

There are 3 ways you can easily do this

1. [With Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/getting-started-with-performance-testing?view=vsts)
2. [With VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test?view=vsts)
3. [Azure Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/app-service-web-app-performance-test?view=vsts#set-up-and-run-your-performance-test)

I prefer going with VSTS